# Fix NSS version not match when update Chrome in Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu

After installing Chrome in Ubuntu, I start Chrome, then encounter the error below:

> [4694:4729:0909/113001.627523:FATAL:nss_util.cc(632)] NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >= 3.26 is required. Please upgrade to the latest NSS, and if you still get this error, contact your distribution maintainer.
>   Aborted (core dumped)

How do I fix it?

Comment: I am also experiencing this on an Ubuntu 16:04 LTS system. It al worked ok until last week when Chrome was updated.

Comment: I am facing the similar problem and in my case the reinstalling the libnss and even reinstalling the chrome to an older version didnt worked

Answer (score 65):

If youre using ubuntu 14.04 then go to terminal

```
sudo apt-get install libnss3
sudo apt-get update
```

if you have google chrome installed then run it

```
google-chrome
```

or install it again

Comment: i use ubuntu 14.04, and i try apt-get update and install.it displays:
libnss3 is already the newest version.

reinstalling many times still not worked.  
finally i degraded the chrome version.

Comment: I use kubuntu 14.04.5 and installing libnss3 solved the issue.

Comment: Pay attention that with me, this solution _per se_ didn't work either. You need to **upgrade ubuntu** first to 16.04 LTS, and then so run these commands. Now it works with me.

Comment: I think the `update` should precede the `install`.  That's how the software manager will know about the newest available version.  `update`, by itself, doesn't update any software -- it just finds out what new software is available (it "updates" the available package database on your machine).

Answer (score 23):

I fixed this issue by updating the libnss3. please follow the following steps for quick fixing.

1. Open 'Software Updater', then click on 'settings' button
2. Tick 'important Security Updates (xenial-security) then close. It will update the cache.
3. Open terminal and the run the command 'sudo apt-get install libnss3'

Now you can open google-chrome. it is worked for me.

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: This is the answer ! Although I would very like to understand the underling mechanism behind the _Tick 'important Security Updates'_

Answer (score 13):

Just had the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04. Solved it by running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade libnss3
```

Explanation: libnss3 is available on Ubuntu 14.04 in 2 versions (see https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libnss3) . I don't really understand the difference between [ports] and [security], but with `sudo apt-get upgrade` I only got the 3.15 version of libnss3 installed. With the commands above I finally got the 3.28 version installed, which satisfies Chrome's requirements of a libnss3 >= 3.26. Chrome now starts correctly.

Answer (score 6):

The Google Chrome required for a libnss3 for running. Try installing libnss3-dev version which solved my similar problem on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

```
 $sudo apt update
 $sudo apt install libnss3-dev
```

And then install the Google chrome downloaded from official google website

```
 $sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable.deb
```

Now to open Google chrome you may either search and open from App launcher or type the following in terminal

```
 $google-chrome-stable
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are running 15.10 and below, the proper way is to upgrade the distro. However if you need to stick to your current version for whatever reason, here is *what I have done*.

I have force install the libnss3 from the upgraded version .deb file along with a dependency requirements.

---

Here is the dependency

```
sudo dpkg -i libnspr4_4.13.1-0ubuntu0.16.10.1_amd64.deb
```

from http://launchpadlibrarian.net/317146464/libnspr4_4.13.1-0ubuntu0.16.10.1_amd64.deb

---

Then, install the libnss3

```
sudo dpkg -i libnss3_3.26.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

from http://launchpadlibrarian.net/295856174/libnss3_3.26.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb

---

You still need to install one more, libnss3-nssdb, which is required for the Chrome as well

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i libnss3-nssdb_3.26.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.2_all.deb
```

from http://launchpadlibrarian.net/296542005/libnss3-nssdb_3.26.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.2_all.deb

=====

I have taken the precaution by backing up these packages from system before installing the upgraded version in case something break and I cannot find the original .deb. In my case, I cannot find the deb for libnss3-nssdb

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg-repack
sudo dpkg-repack libnss3-nssdb
```

Comment: I am using 15.04 and this answer solved my issue and save time. Before this, I cann't open google chrome.

Comment: Amazing! It turns out that this is the appropriate way to install google-chrome on ubuntu 14.04 x64 (lxde desktop)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it seems that this will not be fixed in 15.10.

From : https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nss/+question/657762

> Ubuntu 15.10 is not supported any more (already since July 2016).

I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 15.04 
Chrome 60.0.3112.101 is running fine but 60.0.3112.78 does not.